# What are the Powershell options for the curl included in Windows Server 2016?

Tags: curl, windows-server-2016

I was just able to successfully download a file using the curl included in win server 2016 with the commandline:
`curl URL -o file.mp4`
But commands like `curl -V` and `curl --help` fail.
Are these the wrong parameters for curl within Powershell?
If so what is the correct commandline for `curl --help` within Powershell.

Note: I don't have access to CMD.

Comment: The command `curl`, as is `wget`, is an alias to `invoke-webrequest`.  If you run: `powershell alias curl` you can see the mapping.  Running: `help Invoke-WebRequest` will show the help and confirm the alias entries as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Windows includes the actual curl binary (as versus the alias that PowerShell has by default), you'll find it in C:\Windows\system32\curl.EXE . It may be at a slightly different path depending upon your Windows, "which curl" typed into a Powershell window will return the exact path. Otherwise you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

In powershell curl is actually an alias for another command Invoke-WebRequest.
If you want to use curl you need to provide the path to it  and run it with the arguments provided. It's now installed with windows.

```
$CURLEXE = 'c:\Windows\System32\curl.exe'
$userIDPass = 'yourusername:yourpassword'
$baseURI = 'https://yoururl'

$curlScanArguments = "-u", "$userIDPass",
            '-X', 'POST',
            "$baseURI/resources/jobs/loads",
            '-H', 'accept: application/json',
            '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json',
            '--data', '{ \"resourceName\": \"NAME\"}'

& $CURLEXE @curlArguments
```